# covariance of gaussian random process

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, random, covariance

There is a part of question below.

> Assume $X_n$ is an i.i.d. gaussian random process with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$, find its covariance.

About this part, I have a question, it said $X_n$ is a process, but according to his description, zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$, I think $X_n$ should be a variable, that is, $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{ \sigma \sqrt{2 \pi} }e^{-\frac{1}{2} (\frac{x-m_x}{\sigma})^2}$. Because there are both mean and variance in this pdf, but for the process, there is just mean in the pdf.

Gaussian random process: $\mathbf m$ is mean, and $\mathbf C$ is covariance matrix

$$f_\mathbf X(\mathbf x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi )^{\frac{n}{2}}\sqrt{\det \mathbf C}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf x - \mathbf m)^T \mathbf C^{-1}(\mathbf x - \mathbf m)}$$

So I want to ask is it possible that the question is wrong, that is, the $X_n$ is  actually a variable, not a process? Or if the $X_n$ is actually a process, then how do I calculate the covariance of Gaussian random process when I know the zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$?

Comment: If $X_n$ are iid, covariance is 0 by definition.

Comment: so do you think the $X_n$ is a process or variable?

Comment: For each fixed $n$, $X_n$ is a variable. $\{X_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ is a process.

Comment: so you mean according to his description,zero mean and variance $\sigma ^{2}$,i should use the variable pdf,right?

Comment: Uh, it should depend on what you are using it for; a Gaussian process is uniquely determined by all the pdf of its joint distribution over any finite subset of time indices. If you are using it for to finding its covariance, you just need the pdf for $(X_k, X_l)$ for any arbitrary indices $k, l$.

Comment: but as you said,if $X_n$ are iid,covariance is 0.Why do i still need the pdf for $(X_k,X_l)$?

Comment: I am not sure if you do.

Comment: Distribution for each $X_i$ plus mutual independence condition determines the law of the process $X = \{X_n\}_{n\geq0}$. Without independence, you have to know every multi-dimensional distributions $(X_{i_1},\cdots,X_{i_k})$. Fortunately, for a Gaussian process, it suffices to know the means and covariances.

Comment: @SangchulLee you mean because i know the Gaussian process is iid and  have zero mean ,so i don't need to know  every multi-dimensional distribution,because iid means its covariance must be 0 right?

Comment: Yes. Independence automatically determines all the multi-dimensional distributions in terms of the product of marginal distributions.